# heroku with mysql?

Tags: mysql, heroku

I've writted an app using php, but after several issues with facebook and security (SSL) I moved it from my free webhost to Heroku.

However, after doing that, I'm facing some troubles using my good old MySQL database (still sitting in my old webhost).

I try to connect to the DB using this code:

```
$hostname_fb2 = "mysqldb.000webhost.com";
$database_fb2 = "my_db";
$username_fb2 = "my_user_name";
$password_fb2 = "my_pass";
$fb2 = mysql_pconnect($hostname_fb2, $username_fb2, $password_fb2) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_fb2, $fb2);
$result = mysql_query("select * from users where id='". $my_id ."';",$fb2);
```

Generates this error message (after waiting some time on white screen):

> Warning: mysql_pconnect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110 in /app/www/fb2.php on line 9 Fatal error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110 in /app/www/fb2.php on line 9

So... is there a way to connect the 000webhost's MySQL server, through Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku don't tend to limit the services you can connect to outside of Heroku since they allow the use of lots of addons/services themselves that they don't provide, eg, sendgrid, redistogo, xeroud

Are you able to connect to your existing mysql database from client tools (sequel pro, mysql admin tools etc) on your local machine - it would seem more likely that the problem is more them preventing you accessing your DB as opposed to Heroku limiting it.

Comment: when accesing the mySQL via the same php files that are sitting on the freeweb host everything works smoothly.. its only when i try to access them via the heroku...any idea how to solve that out?

Comment: that's what I'm saying is the problem, the freeweb host limits access to their own network - this is pretty common practice. You best get in touch with their support to find out if they permit inbound connections to their mysql instances from outside of their own network